# What does "sufficiently large future funding needs" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[Huang 2021](https://academic.oup.com/rfs/article/34/4/1789/5897423) states that

> If firms anticipate sufficiently large future funding needs and have a
> relatively modest amount of unused debt capacity, they forego
> borrowing nowand instead issue costly equity to meet an immediate
> funding need

I am wondering what does "sufficiently large future funding needs" mean. Actually, I do not understand what does "sufficient need" mean in this case.

Comment: It's a slightly unusual context, because normally-positive ***sufficiently large*** modifies normally-negative ***funding needs***. Where the condition being "queried" by ***if*** is whether those "needs" are ***big enough*** to justify issuing more shares (as opposed to simply borrowing more money from the bank).

Answer (score 1):

The sentence is saying:

that if firms need a lot of investment in future
and are not able to borrow much more money (i.e. from the banks)
they can raise money
by issuing shares (i.e. equity)
(that investors buy on the stock market,
thus providing the firms with the money they require.)

By way of background, a company has two ways of raising money.
It can either borrow the money (if it can find lenders/investors)
or it can issue shares that are sold to investors.

In the statement above, the writer is suggesting the share issue option. In practice, big companies will consider both options, as one may be more advantageous than the other.

Comment: Also, "sufficient" in this case is a synonym for "enough." "If the firms' needs are [great] enough..."

Comment: The actual text says nothing about whether the board might ***lose control*** if they "dilute" their shareholding by issuing new shares - it just says this is a "costly" option, which I understand as being a literal reference to it being ***expensive***, not ***risky***.

Comment: True... a case of being overly helpful! Will take it out.